# video playing in local system but now in intranet in remote system

Tags: java, struts2

I embeeded the media player in my jsp using struts2 as i retrive the pathfrom the Database and read the content from the folder in my local system it is working fine But when i acces my web page in other system i am unable to play it and here is my code

```
                <object width="320" height="384"
                    standby="Loading Windows Media Player components..."
                    type="video/x-ms-asf"
                    classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6"
                    style="background-color: #000000;">
                    <param name="autostart" value="1">
                    <param name="uiMode" value="full" />
                    <param name="autosize" value="1">

                    <param name="playcount" value="1">
                    <param name="height" value="384" />
                    <param name="width" value="320" />
                    <param name="autoStart" value="1" />
                    <param name="autoPlay" value="1" />
                    <param name="AnimationatStart" value="1" />
                    <param name="showdisplay" value="1" />
                    <param name="TransparentAtStart" value="0" />
                    <param name="ShowControls" value="1" />

                    <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="1" />
                    <param name="ClickToPlay" value="0" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
                    <param name="volume" value="100%" />
                    <param name="InvokeURLs" value="0" />
                    <param name="loop" value="0" />
                    <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" width="320" height="384"
                        autostart="true" showcontrols="true"
                        src="\\C:\\Users\\raghavender.g\\Desktop\1.mp4" />

                </object>


            </div>
```

Comment: *"i am unable to play it"*  (sigh) How do you expect to debug this with that level of information?  What is reported in the Java Console?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this part:

```
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" width="320" height="384"
                    autostart="true" showcontrols="true"
                    src="\\C:\\Users\\raghavender.g\\Desktop\1.mp4" />
```

You can't source the video data in from a file local to your server machine and have it work on a client machine.  You need to host the video file on your server as well, and then change your `embed` to something more like:

```
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" width="320" height="384"
                    autostart="true" showcontrols="true"
                    src="http://myserver.com/videos/Desktop1.mp4" />
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply it solved my issue thanks but when i added http://192.168.105.68/video/1.mp4 i was unable to play but when i removed HTTP i was able to play over network may i know the issue